# No metadata in Internet Explorer

Tags: managed-metadata, internet-explorer

A user is unable to select metadata from the pop up window when trying to tag a document when uploading.  But if Chrome is used it is OK.  Clearly a browser issue.  Which setting in IE could be causing this?[image]

Comment: What version of IE are they using and are they using 32 bit or 64 bit IE?

Comment: Whenever something doesn't work in IE, I check compatability mode settings first (change on to off, or vice-versa)

Comment: 32bit Version 11, I suspect it's a policy or security setting but I'm not sure which one?

Comment: try with Enterprise Mode(compatibility mode), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640687.aspx

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did you ever get a resolution on this?